# How to count even and odd numbers in a list of numbers

Tags: haskell

I want to write a function that will tell me the number of even and odd number occurences within a list. For example, if my list was [1,2,3,4,5], I want it to return (2,3).

This is what I have so far

```
counteven :: [Integer] -> Integer
counteven [] = 0
counteven (x:xs) 
     |(x `div` 2) == 0 = 1 + counteven xs
     |otherwise = counteven xs

countodd :: [Integer] -> Integer
countodd [] = 0
countodd (x:xs) 
     |(x `div` 2) /= 0 = 1 + countodd xs
     |otherwise = countodd xs

oddsAndEvens :: [Integer] -> (Integer,Integer)
oddsAndEvens (x:xs) = ((counteven(x:xs)),(countodd(x:xs)))
```

It does run on my text editor but I am getting strange results.
Can someone please help me what the problem might be?

Comment: What are 'strange results'? We can't help you if we don't know your problem.

Comment: oddsAndEvens ns = (odds, length ns - odds) where odds = length (filter odd ns)

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 3):

You have two problems.

### Problem 1: `div` vs `mod`.

`div` divides numbers. `mod` takes their remainder. For example, `div 6 2 = 3`, and `mod 6 2 = 0`.

You incorrectly use `div`. That should be `mod`, so for instance your first function should be:

```
counteven :: [Integer] -> Integer
counteven [] = 0
counteven (x:xs)
  | x `mod` 2 == 0   = 1 + counteven xs -- NOTE: `mod` not `div`!
  | otherwise        = counteven xs
```

I'm sure you can fix `countodd` on your own given this example.

### Problem two: over-restrictive pattern matching.

Your final function has an issue too:

```
oddsAndEvens :: [Integer] -> (Integer, Integer)
oddsAndEvens (x:xs) = (counteven (x:xs), countodd (x:xs))
```

The argument `(x:xs)` only pattern matches on non-empty lists, so `oddsAndEvens []` will produce an error, since you haven't defined its behaviour.

It *should* be:

```
oddsAndEvens :: [Integer] -> (Integer, Integer)
oddsAndEvens xs = (counteven xs, countodd xs)
```

Since `xs` matches anything, the function will now work for empty and nonempty lists.

Comment: Thank you for your fast feedback! I'll try to write some more codes considering your advice in mind

Answer (score 2):

Another solution:

```
import           Data.List         (partition)
import           Data.Tuple.Extra  (both)

countEvenAndOdd :: Integral a => [a] -> (Int, Int)
countEvenAndOdd x = both length (partition even x)
```

Answer (score 0):

Prelude has a function `odd :: Int -> Bool` which checks if number is odd or not. So, filter all odd numbers and find the size of it. All other numbers are even numbers.

```
c :: [Int] -> (Int, Int)
c as = (odds, evens)
    where odds  = length $ filter odd as
          evens = length as - odds
```

Answer (score 0):

You only have to determine the count of one of the even/odd in the list. You have the length of the list. The length of the list minus the count of one of the even/odd in the list is the remainder or other number in the list.

```
let l = [1..5]
let l1 = [length [ n | n <- l, mod n 2 == 0]]!!0
[l1,(length l) - l1]
-> [2,3]
```

One line with a nested list comprehension to do assignments without do.

```
[[l1,l2] | l1 <-[length [ n | n <- l, mod n 2 == 0]], l2 <-[length l - l1]]!!0
```

Yields the same.